# Animation on view appear and disappear

Tags: ios, swift

I want this to animate for 5 seconds and disappear after 4 seconds:

```swift
IBAction func animate(_ sender: Any) {
    var frame = viewForAnimation.frame
    
    if showFilterMenu == false {
        self.viewForAnimation.alpha = 0.0
        self.viewForAnimation.isHidden = false
        self.showFilterMenu = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6,
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        self?.viewForAnimation.alpha = 1.0
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6,
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        self?.viewForAnimation.alpha = 0.0
        }) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.viewForAnimation.isHidden = true
            self?.showFilterMenu = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, you need to change the duration to 5 from 0.6, And in the closure of the first UIView.animate you can do a .asyncAfter:4 to fire the 2nd animation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your timer of 4 second you can call this line of code

self.imageAnim.layer.removeAllAnimations()